# Minimize power, but still have remote desktop

Tags: windows-8.1, remote-desktop, power

I am running Windows 8.1 on a ASUS M5A97 r2.0 motherboard.  When idle, the system uses about 70 watts. When asleep, it only uses 5 watts, but remote desktop obviously does not work in this state.

I have created my own power plan.  I have the disks set to turn off after 20 minutes and Processor power mgmt, minimum processor state set to 1%.  Display is set to turn off after 10 minutes.

What BIOS settings (already set to power-saver mode in the EZ menu) in the advanced menu and what settings in Windows 8.1 can I use to still have remote desktop accessible but use less electricity?  I want to have RDP access, but it may be a few hours after I have physically left my system.

Comment: Really the only thing you need to enable us WOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did end up going the WoL route.  Since my ASUS RT-n66u router always stays on, I can remotely connect to it to issue the WoL packets.  This seems to work very reliably.